# A fixed object inside a fixed object

Tags: html, css

I have an interactive background on my website, but the "content" of the site interfere. So I appliedd a position: fixed; to the content of the site, but inside this content there are two objects with position: fixed, that were supposed to move with the page scrolling, but now they don't. How can I fix this? Check out the site http://buddhatest.comyr.com/
The object at the left and the object at the right should move down if you scroll the page but the don't.

Comment: your link doesn't match the description in stated in your problem

Comment: @noob This are the two objects I'm talking about http://prntscr.com/5y0dm0

Comment: use the style position:fixed; top:0 on both the objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**fixed**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#fixed)
>   The background is fixed with regard to the **viewport**. In paged media where there is no viewport, a ‘fixed’ background is fixed with respect to the page box and therefore replicated on every page. Note that **there is only one viewport per view**. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism (see the ‘[overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow)’ property [CSS21](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#ref-CSS21)), a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element.

Comment: And what could be a possible solution?